# Sorting a database js generated table

Tags: jquery, node.js, ejs

I want to create a table displaying db information using ejs and nodes.js.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="loaded-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Second</th>
            <th>Third</th>
            <th>Fourth</th>
            <th>Fifth</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <% for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) { %>
        <tr>
            <td> <%= data[i].prsnl_firstName %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].prsnl_lastName %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].prsnl_city %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].prsnl_email %> </td>
            <td> <%= data[i].prsnl_age %> </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I also want it to be sortable. Like in wikipedia, where you click on one of the `th` and the table is sorted by that column.
The problem is, trying to use a jquery plugin doesn't work because the table is literally none existent at the moment of executing the code.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you can use your `JQuery plugin` (Example http://tablesorter.com/docs/), but you have to make sure you execute the sortable behavior after the table is created, you have to scenarios:

1) The table is created when the page is rendered, for this case you will need run using `document on ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
       $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
});
```

2) If your table is created after some trigger, just run `$("#myTable").tablesorter();` or equivalent after the trigger.

Comment: I'm sorry, something isn't working. when i do  it with a normal table it works but for a generated table, it shows the table but doesn't do anything